# How to temporarily remove dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Is there any way I could temporarily 
disable grub so that it would by default boot into Windows 10. I would like to undo it when I need Ubuntu and the dual boot screen back.

Comment: If UEFI install you can change boot-order in UEFI-settings.

Comment: I'm with @mook765, Windows has its own boot loader. In BIOS you can change your boot order, set Windows as first so it will skip Grub in its entirety.

Comment: @mook765 point is simply superb.

Comment: But majority of laptops or PC's accept only boot from HDD or USB one at a time.

Comment: Thank you all.. mine is not UEFI, so I could not find that option.. but the UEFI option seems a whole bit simpler and easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. To do so, you may want to edit your **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** to mark as comments Ubuntu entry lines (make Ubuntu entry inactive) and leave the rest as is. This way you "remove" (hide) temporarily your dualboot so only another OS will be shown on the bootloader.

To revert it back, simply unmark the comments you made (make Ubuntu entry active).

Comment: 1) The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` gets overwritten by the `update-grub` command. 2) How would you edit the file when you always boot into Windows after the change?

Comment: @PerlDuck hi Perl: 1) you don't have to run `update-grub` to get the result 2) by having a LiveCD of Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux of course.

Comment: Thank you.. that should work. I was hoping I could edit from windows using some utility that could read ext file system.

Comment: @UdayKiran what utility did you use? how did it work out?